# Windows Phone 8 - Expandable menu list

Tags: listview, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, expandablelistview, application-bar

I want to create custom Application Bar which when expanded would containts list of items and each item could navigate to other page but item would have arrow too (or some icon) and after tap it could expand to subitems which goes to different pages.

In recent times I didn't do much programming for Windows Phone. I know that there was ExpanderView in Toolkit but I was searching and it's not actual. So I am asking which is best way to do this in Windows Phone 8(.1)? When control collapsed it should look like ApplicationBar but when expanded it would contains list of items which could be expanded too but it also could be navigating to another pages. Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you'd need to develop your own XAML control to achieve this. I don't think there's anything built in to the framework that does exactly what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

An ExpanderControl is implemented from [Bewise](http://bewisephonecontrols.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20the%20BPC%20ExpanderControl&referringTitle=Documentation). You can make use of it and build a custom app bar.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently added an [**ExpandPanel for Windows/Windows Phone 8.1+ in GitHub**](https://github.com/harikrishnant1991/WindowsPhone_ExpandPanelSample). Do check it out. All you need to do is include it in your project as specified in the readme file.